# Net Copy and Data Check in Google Stress App Test

Tags: android, stress-testing

I have developed **Google StressAppTest for Android devices** for almost all platforms.

By using this application, I want to know the results for **Net Copy**, **Disk** and **Data Check** by running some test cases.
From the help provided by google I am not able to know how to make test cases to check for above Statistics.

For more information, Check this link: https://code.google.com/p/stressapptest/

You can find help to make test cases from "User Guide" given in above link.

One of the sample results is attached here:

```
Command to run in cmd: adb shell /data/local/tmp/stressapptest -M 256 -s 30 -W
```

Result of above test case:

```
Stats: Memory Copy: xxxxx.xxM at xxx.xxMB/s
Stats: File Copy: 0.00M at 0.00MB/s
Stats: Net Copy: 0.00M at 0.00MB/s
Stats: Data Check: 0.00M at 0.00MB/s
Stats: Invert Data: 0.00M at 0.00MB/s
Stats: Disk: 0.00M at 0.00MB/s
```

Comment: So what is the question here. You ported the Stress App Test to Android but can't get it to work?

Comment: The Stress App Test is working proerly and I am getting Statastics for Memory Copy and File Copy by writing test cases, but I don't know how to make the test cases to get the statastics for Net Copy, Disk and Data Check.